# This expression won't change all occurrences of "." to "-" in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Instead it changes everything in the string to dashes. Can someone explain why it is doing that? 
Here is the expression:

```
var replaceDots = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/./g, '-');
}
```

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile now. I know it will work without being placed inside of the var replaceDots. It needs to be inside the variable to complete the question.

Comment: With RegEx, the period `.` is a wildcard that represents any character, which is why it changes everything to dashes. Try this: `str.replace(/\./g, '-')` since if you want to represent the period itself and not a wildcard, you need to escape it with the backslash `\`.

Answer (score 4):

`.` has a special meaning in regexes. It means "any character" or "any character except newline" depending on the flavour  (it excludes line terminators in JS). You want `/\./g` (i.e. escape the `.`)

Comment: Upvoted for being the only answer that provides an explanation.